# Is there any way to change the position of ValueLabel in .Net Chart?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, charts, asp.net-charts

I want to change position of ValueLabel of my chart. What is the solution?

Also can I change size of that?

Answer (score 2):

I think I am too late, but as I had the same problem and found a solution, here it is:

```
yourChart.Series["yourSeries"]["LabelStyle"] = "Right";
```

This changes the position of the value label, NOT the axis label!

Answer (score 1):

Did you try setting the [`LabelStyle`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd489245.aspx) which is a Custom property. here you can specify the positioning within the predefined ones like

- Top, Bottom, Right, Left, TopLeft, TopRight, BottomLeft, BottomRight,
  Center

Comment: I want to change label style of ValueLabel not AxisLabel.

Comment: Could you give an example, i think i missed something

Comment: I don't want to labels of series have any overlapping.

Answer (score 0):

You can set the position by this way :

```
<Points>               
      <asp:DataPoint AxisLabel="1" YValues="14" />
      <asp:DataPoint AxisLabel="2" YValues="11" />
      <asp:DataPoint AxisLabel="3" YValues="16" />
      <asp:DataPoint AxisLabel="4" YValues="4" />
      <asp:DataPoint AxisLabel="5" YValues="3" /> 
</Points>
```